# if beta=infinity, what is Vo/Vbe?

Tags: transistors, npn, pnp, pn-junction

So i've been given this problem and i really don't know how to approach to solve it. What i know is that if beta is infinity, then Ib1 will be zero, then ie1 and ie2 will alse be zero(if i'm right). But are both transistors dead after that? How can i determine the value for Vbe(on)?
I know it's not such a hard problem but i've been stuck and would appreciate your help
thanks

[image]

Comment: HINT: Do you know what Vbe would be for your "ideal" transistor? If you know that you can calculate the voltage on the base of Qi. If you know that you can calculate I and hence Vo.

Comment: Also, you might want to look up what a Vbe multiplier is. As for your doubt about Ie, you should consider that 0 times infinity can be a finite number (I hope there are no mathematicians reading this).

Comment: @Trevor it hasn't been mentioned what Vbe value is. But if we suppose we know, how can i calculate knowing that? would you please explain a bit more

Comment: The base of a transistor is usually modeled as a diode, so a single Vbe is normally approximated to be 0.7V. => So what does the voltage at the base of Qi need to be to turn on your transistors.

Comment: BTW the whole task question is a bit off... You need to assume some source resistance in Vo or all bets are off for Vo.

Comment: @Trevor Why? The transistors will limit the current to the value needed to have the "right" value of Vo.

Comment: @SredniVashtar ya but if this is an 'ideal X' type question, you could just as easily say Vo is an ideal voltage source at whatever voltage you care to mention... The transistors would just suck up that voltage... Being ideal, they would survive LOL. You have to make an assumption somewhere.

Comment: I see what you mean, but when you look at the Vbe multiplier as a special 'flexible' diode, you usually don't care about the rest of the circuit. In the same way one does not mind the fact that an ideal diode has a perfectly vertical characteristic when V>V_threshold. As a matter of fact, we can find the characteristic of this bipole without even knowing what is the actual value of Vbe. The ideality in this case is assuming Ib=0 to make calculations easier. But you are right that in a real circuit this ideal component would create havoc (as an ideal diode would).

Answer (score 0):

If beta is infinity then I<sub>B</sub> will be infinitely small (*not* zero) and I<sub>E</sub> can be whatever you want. All that means is that Q1's Base draws negligible current, so it has negligible effect on the voltage at the junction of R1 and R2.

Even though each transistor has infinite gain it still needs a bias voltage (V<sub>BE</sub>) to start drawing current. So if V<sub>O</sub> divided by the resistor ratio is higher than 2 x V<sub>BE</sub> then I<sub>E</sub> will increase and pull V<sub>O</sub> down until the voltages are equal, and if V<sub>O</sub> is lower then I<sub>E</sub> will reduce allowing V<sub>O</sub> to rise.

The end result is that V<sub>O</sub> will equal 2 x V<sub>BE</sub> multiplied by the resistor ratio (R1+R2)/R2.